# Fluent NHibernate not mapping child rows to a collection property (DB2 Database)

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

**Background:**

I am working on a legacy DB2 database, so I have no control over the schema. I have searched this site for answers and have found none.  I have also searched google and not found a suitable answer.

The tables described herein both utilize composite keys. I have a parent table that stores eligibility information per "case".  The child table stores eligibility information regarding each individual associated with the case.  The child records are differentiated by pin number to make them unique in the child table only.

I am using NHibernate v3.1 with Fluent NHibernate v1.2, both acquired via NuGet packages.  The entities are mapped in using the Fluent NHibernate auto-mapper functionality.  Any custom mapping is done in the mapping override method for each entity.

Another thing to know is that these tables do not have a "primary key" defined in DB2.  They only have "unique keys", which are what you see in the composite key definition below (see code).

T0026_AG_ELIG is the name of the parent table and the corresponding POCO class.
T0265_AG_IN_ELIG is the name of the child table and the corresponding POCO class.

**Problem:**

The problem is that when I execute the query, all the data is queried, the parent record is successfully mapped to the class, but the returned child rows do not map into the collection on the parent class.  NHibernate does generate the queries for the parent and child data.  When I execute my own query against the database, the correct data for the conditions does come back.  For some reason, the child records are just not being bound to the property on the parent (T0026) class.

**Question:**

What do I need to do to get the multiple rows coming back from T0265_AG_IN_ELIG to map to their corresponding class and load properly into the specified collection property on the parent class (T0026_AG_ELIG)?

**Collection Property of Parent (T0026_AG_ELIG):**

```
Public Overridable Property IndividualEligibilityRecords As IList(Of T0265_AG_IN_ELIG)
```

**Mapping Override for Parent (T0026_AG_ELIG):**

```
mapping.CompositeId() _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.CASE_NUM) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.PROGRAM_CD) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.SUBPROGRAM_CD) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.AG_SEQ_NUM) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM)

mapping.HasMany(Of T0265_AG_IN_ELIG)(Function(x) x.IndividualEligibilityRecords) _
   .Cascade.All() _
   .Inverse() _
   .Fetch.Join() _
   .KeyColumns.Add("CASE_NUM") _
   .KeyColumns.Add("PROGRAM_CD") _
   .KeyColumns.Add("SUBPROGRAM_CD") _
   .KeyColumns.Add("AG_SEQ_NUM") _
   .KeyColumns.Add("CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM") _
   .Not.LazyLoad() _
   .AsList(Function(x) x.Column("PIN_NUM"))


   mapping.IgnoreProperty(Function(x) x.IndividualEligibilityRecords)
```

**Mapping Override for Child (T0265_AG_IN_ELIG):**

```
mapping.CompositeId() _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.CASE_NUM) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.PROGRAM_CD) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.SUBPROGRAM_CD) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.AG_SEQ_NUM) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.PIN_NUM)
```

**The following code executes to execute the query:**

```
transaction = session.BeginTransaction()

query = session.CreateQuery("FROM T0026_AG_ELIG AS T0026 " _
      & "WHERE T0026.CASE_NUM = :p0 AND T0026.PROGRAM_CD = :p1 AND " _
      & "SUBPROGRAM_CD = :p2 AND AG_SEQ_NUM = :p3 AND CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM = :p4")

query.SetParameter("p0", caseNumber)
query.SetParameter("p1", programCode)
query.SetParameter("p2", subProgramCode)
query.SetParameter("p3", agSequenceNumber)
query.SetParameter("p4", cagEligSequenceNumber)

result = query.List()
transaction.Commit()

If result.Count = 1 Then
   Return DirectCast(result.Item(0), T0026_AG_ELIG)
End If
```

Comment: can you check the sql generated for your query and run that directly on the db? And what is `mapping.IgnoreProperty(Function(x) x.IndividualEligibilityRecords)` good for? I think you can leave it

Comment: I have captured the queries that NHibernate is generating and have successfully executed those queries.

The execution of the NHibernate command "List()" generates 5 separate queries. The first returns the top-level record as it should. The second one returns the three child records attached to the parent record. The 3rd, 4th and 5th queries return each of the child records individually, which is completely unnecessary. I am not sure why NHibernate is generating the last 3 queries.

Perhaps when NHibernate only generates the first and second queries, the collection will get mapped correctly?

Comment: The "queries" being the SQL queries that NHibernate is generating.  Also, I was able to remove the "IgnoreProperty" call without issue.

Comment: can you try `var result = session.Get<T0026_AG_ELIG>(new T0026_AG_ELIG{ CASE_NUM = caseNumber, PROGRAM_CD = programCode, SUBPROGRAM_CD = subProgramCode, AG_SEQ_NUM = agSequenceNumber, CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM = cagEligSequenceNumber })` as VB?

Comment: The VB version is: **Dim result = session.Get(Of T0026_AG_ELIG)(New T0026_AG_ELIG() With {.CASE_NUM = caseNumber, .PROGRAM_CD = programCode, .SUBPROGRAM_CD = subProgramCode, .AG_SEQ_NUM = agSequenceNumber, .CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM = cagEligSequenceNumber})** The SQL queries it generates are identical to those that are generated by the execution code in the original post. The parent object is mapped, but the children are not mapped into the collection property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post in an answer because its much easier to read and edit.

My next guess is that NH is confused by the different number of key columns in the hasmany of `T0265_AG_IN_ELIG` and its compositekey. normally this kind of association is a dependent association where the child-entities are not mapped seperatly but within the collection. Try exclude `T0265_AG_IN_ELIG` from automapping and mapping it like this in `T0026_AG_ELIG`

```
mapping.HasMany(Of T0265_AG_IN_ELIG)(Function(x) x.IndividualEligibilityRecords) _
   .Cascade.All() _
   .Inverse() _
   .KeyColumns.Add("CASE_NUM", "PROGRAM_CD", "SUBPROGRAM_CD", "AG_SEQ_NUM", "CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM") _
   .Not.LazyLoad() _
   .AsList(Function(x) x.Column("PIN_NUM"))
   .Component(Function(c) c.ParentReference(Function(x) x.T0026_AG_ELIG))
```

Update:

What is the value of:

```
DirectCast(result.Item(0), T0026_AG_ELIG).IndividualEligibilityRecords.GetType().Name
```

Update: of yourse when you have excluded T0265_AG_IN_ELIG from automapping you have to specify all columns in the component

```
class AutomapConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type != typeof(T0265_AG_IN_ELIG);
    }
}

class T0265_AG_IN_ELIG
{
    public T0026_AG_ELIG T0026_AG_ELIG { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}


.Component(c =>
{
    c.ParentReference(x => x.T0026_AG_ELIG);
    c.Map(x => x.Prop1));
    c.Map(x => x.Prop2));
    c.Map(x => x.Prop3));
})
```

Comment: Only problem with the code is that the component line breaks because "ParentReference" does not return a value -- it's a sub.  .Component(Function(c) **c.ParentReference(Function(x) x.T0026_AG_ELIG)**)

Comment: in C# it would be `.Component(c => c.ParentReference(x => x.T0026_AG_ELIG))` maybe `.Component(Sub(c) c.ParentReference(Function(x) x.T0026_AG_ELIG))`?

Comment: That fixed the code.  Now I am getting the parent record populated, but the child collection "IndividualEligibilityRecords" is still not getting populated.  NHibernate generates one select query for the parent record, and one select query for the 3 child records.  They are selected, but never mapped into the collection.

Comment: Another odd thing I've discovered is that while the `.Component(Sub(c) c.ParentReference(Function(x) x.Parent))` line does reduce the SQL select statements down to two (one for T0026, one for T0265), it also prevents all columns on T0265 from being selected.  I've looked for a way to specify all columns for selection without success.  Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Update: I was able to get the collection to load if I specified in the T0026 mapping to use `ExtraLazyLoad()` instead of disabling lazy load.  However, this means that my session must remain open to query those extra items, which is less than desirable.  When I switch the code back to use `Not.LazyLoad()`, the collection fails to load and has the error "No Children Available".  Also of note is that the `.Component(Sub(c) c.ParentReference(Function(x) x.Parent))` line is commented out in this case.

Comment: Firo, thank you for your help.  Your assistance went a long way toward getting me to the solution.  I have posted below what we ultimately figured out.  However, I wanted to make sure I gave credit where credit was due.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out.  Essentially, there is some issue in NHibernate 3.1 that will only let records bind when using Extra Lazy Loading.  Even then, SQL is improperly generated from the HQL.  The solution to this was to revert to using Fluent NHibernate 1.2 with NHibernate 2.1.2.

The link for the download is titled "Download for NHibernate 2.1.2".  Click below to go to the downloads page.

[Fluent NHibernate Downloads Page](http://fluentnhibernate.org/downloads)

**Mapping Override for T0026:**

```
mapping.CompositeId() _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.CASE_NUM) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.PROGRAM_CD) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.SUBPROGRAM_CD) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.AG_SEQ_NUM) _
   .KeyProperty(Function(x) x.CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM) _

mapping.HasMany(Of T0265_AG_IN_ELIG)(Function(x) x.IndividualEligibilityRecords) _
   .KeyColumns.Add("CASE_NUM", "PROGRAM_CD", "SUBPROGRAM_CD", "AG_SEQ_NUM", "CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM") _
   .Cascade.All() _
   .Table("PWS639TC.T0265_AG_IN_ELIG") _
   .Not.LazyLoad() _
   .AsBag()
```

The main differences in the mapping file are that we are not using the inverse and we are returning a "GenericPersistentBag" from NHibernate.

**Query Execution Method:**

```
transaction = session.BeginTransaction()

query = session.CreateQuery("FROM T0026_AG_ELIG AS T0026 " _
              & "WHERE T0026.CASE_NUM = :p0 " _
              & "AND T0026.PROGRAM_CD = :p1 " _
              & "AND SUBPROGRAM_CD = :p2 " _
              & "AND AG_SEQ_NUM = :p3 " _
              & "AND CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM = :p4")

query.SetParameter("p0", caseNumber)
query.SetParameter("p1", programCode)
query.SetParameter("p2", subProgramCode)
query.SetParameter("p3", agSequenceNumber)
query.SetParameter("p4", cagEligSequenceNumber)

result = query.List()

If result.Count = 1 Then
   returnable = DirectCast(result.Item(0), T0026_AG_ELIG)
End If

transaction.Commit()
```

The query execution method is identical.